# Ember-Data - Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Just trying to get a fiddle set up to solve a few other issues, and I cant get passed what should be a simple setup.

In older version of ember, I can get access to Fixture data using find():
http://jsfiddle.net/jdcravens/Btum7/

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: "DS.FixtureAdapter"
});

App.Team = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    colors: DS.attr('string')
})

App.Team.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Celtics',
    colors: 'Green, White'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Lakers',
    colors: 'Yellow, Black'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Bulls',
    colors: 'Red, Black'
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Mavericks',
    colors: 'Blue, White'
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Spurs',
    colors: 'Black, Grey, White'
}];

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend();
App.Router.map(function (match) {
  match("/").to("home");
});

App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        controller.set('content', App.Team.find());
    }
});
```

And use the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
  <ul class="teams">
  {{#each team in content}}
    <li>{{team.name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>    
</script>
```

But in all of the latest libraries, I get App.Team as undefined: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jdcravens/JTWjU/6/

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: "DS.FixtureAdapter"
});

App.Team = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    colors: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Team.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Celtics',
    colors: 'Green, White'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Lakers',
    colors: 'Yellow, Black'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Bulls',
    colors: 'Red, Black'
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Mavericks',
    colors: 'Blue, White'
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Spurs',
    colors: 'Black, Grey, White'
}];

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("home", {path: "/"})
});

App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller) {
        console.log(App)
        controller.set('content', App.Team.find());
    }
});
```

I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. You are using an outdated version of Ember Data.

You can get the latest ember data at: http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.js

Update the ember-data.js file and it will work.

Comment: Arg ... yea Revision 10, someone needs to delete: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/emberjs/data/ember-data-latest.min.js